# PHP / MySQL > 6.99 x 100 = 600?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very strange problem here:

I have the value 6.99 stored in a MySQL table called `amount`. I get following outputs:

```
echo $amount;         // 6.99
echo $amount * 100;   // 600
echo 6.99 * 100;      // 699
```

The 2nd value is obviously wrong. Here and then I do calculations, but I have never seen that error. What is happening here?

I use XAMPP on Win7 if that matters.

Comment: And with which code do you get these results?

Comment: I use PHP. I think I found it. The value gets as '6.99' stored in MySQL AFTER the calculation. But I do the math before storing it and a var_dump() gives me:  object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["currencyID"]=> string(3) "EUR" } [0]=> string(4) "6.99" }     so obiously it's an object that makes trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The .99 is getting dropped when a string is being converted to an integer.

If you were to do `var_dump('6.99')` it would be different than `var_dump(6.99)`

There's many ways to convert strings to floats. Here's one way:

```
$amount = floatval('6.99');
echo $amount*100;
```

If the intention is for this to go into MySQL, I'd recommend that you don't use floats. Especially if this is having to to do with currency. I normally store currency as decimal, and in php I handle it as an int of pennies.

Comment: I did now:  `$amount = (string)$amount; `   That works. Should I do that before storing numbers in MySQL?